# Probability of Improvement (PI) acquisition function for Bayesian Optimization

Tags: optimization, bayesian

I was trying to better understand the intuition behind *Probability of Improvement (PI)* acquisition function in the field of **Bayesian Optimization**

This acquisition function chooses the next point as the one with highest *probability of improvement* over the current max $f(x^+)$, and we can write the selection of next point as follows:

$$x_{t+1} = arg\max (\alpha_{PI}(x)) = arg \max((P(f(x) \ge  f(x^+)+\epsilon)))$$

where $x^+$ is the current optimum point.

Typically, having an initial dataset of available points and evaluations $\mathcal{D} = \{x_i, f(x_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ one uses a *Gaussian Process regression* to build a surrogate model for the black-box function $f$. Given this consideration, it is possible to rewrite the original equation as

$$x_{t+1} = arg\max_{x} \Phi\left(\frac{\mu_t(x) - f(x^+)-\epsilon}{\sigma_t(x)}\right)$$

with $\Phi(\cdot)$ indicating the CDF.

To me it's not yet clear how to get to the second equation by starting from the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result by a change of variables. Let's fix some notation.
At time $t+1$ you have observed $(x_1, y_1), \dots, (x_t, y_t)$ and you can build the functions $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$ (mean and variance) based on this data. You can also define $x^+=\text{arg}\max_{i=1,\dots, t}f(x_i)$. Notice that if there is no noise in your observations (which I believe to be your case), then $x^+$ does not depend on the chosen model $f$, as it coincides with an observed $y_i$, for some $i=1, \dots, t$.
Since the right hand side of $f(x) \geq f(x^+) + \varepsilon$ is fixed (not a random variable)
$$\begin{aligned}\mathbb{P}(f(x) \geq f(x^+) + \varepsilon) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\sigma_t(x)^2}} \int^{\infty}_{f(x^+) + \varepsilon}\exp\left
(-\frac{(r-\mu_t(x))^2}{2\sigma_t(x)^2}\right)dr\\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int^{\frac{\mu_t(x))^2 -f(x^+) - \varepsilon}{2\sigma_t(x)^2}}_{-\infty}\exp\left
(-\frac{s^2}{2}\right)ds\end{aligned},$$
where the change of variables is $s= -\frac{r - \mu_t(x)}{\sigma_t(x)}$.
The rightmost element in the chain of equalities is the cdf of the standard Gaussian evaluated at $\frac{\mu_t(x))^2 -f(x^+) - \varepsilon}{2\sigma_t(x)^2}.$